# Consulta con multiple where mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Amigos estoy realizando una consulta en la cual me tiene que traer la cantidad de post publicado en base a una determinada cantidad de id categoría, la cuestión es que haciendo la consulta no me muestra un resultado pero técnicamente si tiene que haber un resultado mostrar unas 5 coincidencia pero no lo genera, para esto utilizo dos tablas `pv_post` contiene todas las publicaciones y `pv_cat_post` que contiene la relación entre la cantidad de categorías asociadas a esa publicación, esta es la consulta estoy hasta el momento tratando de hacer.

```
SELECT
pv_post.id_post AS ID,
pv_post.titulo AS TIT,
pv_post.img1 AS IMG,
pv_post.contenido AS CONT,
pv_post.fech_creacion AS FECH
FROM
pv_post
INNER JOIN pv_post_categoria ON pv_post_categoria.id_post = pv_post.id_post
INNER JOIN pv_categoria ON pv_post_categoria.id_categoria = pv_categoria.id_categoria
WHERE pv_categoria.id_categoria = 1 AND pv_categoria.id_categoria = 30
```

La cuestión es que si hay publicación que cumplen con esa misma condición, existen un par de publicaciones con la categoría `id=1` y la categoría `id=30`.

Alguien podría ayudarme en esta consulta.

Comment: para que cumpla una u otra condición, es decir, sea 1 o 30, utiliza OR: WHERE pv_categoria.id_categoria = 1 OR pv_categoria.id_categoria = 30

Comment: ¿Necesitas las publicaciones que estén en ambas categorías a la vez, o basta con que estén en una de ellas?

Answer (score 4):

Tienes un error lógico, en la linea

```
WHERE pv_categoria.id_categoria = 1 AND pv_categoria.id_categoria = 30
```

evalúas que la columna id_categoria de la tabla pv_categoria sea AL MISMO tiempo 1 y 30, es algo ilógico, revisa tu query